# What is the meaning of a robots.txt that only contains 'User-agent: *'?

Tags: web, web-crawler, robots.txt

I am trying to crawl a website but the robots.txt has just the following line:

```
User-agent: *
```

Does it mean that it doesn't care if I crawl their website?

Comment: It means that the following lines in the same group apply to all user-agents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if `User-agent: *` is the only line in the robots.txt, you are allowed to crawl everything.

Only `Disallow` lines have the power to list (beginnings of) URL paths that must not be crawled. If a robots.txt has no `Disallow` lines, nothing is disallowed.

That said, the author of that robots.txt may have made an error. `User-agent` lines are typically followed by `Disallow` lines (or others, like `Allow` etc.). There is no point in starting a record¹, but not stating anything for the matched user agents.

---

¹ A record starts with one or multiple `User-agent` lines, and is separated from other records by a blank line. `User-agent: *` matches all user agents not matched by any other `User-agent` line in that robots.txt.